# What is causing No OpKernel for 'Less' in Keras and how can i remove it for inference?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I had a model created with the Keras framework. I was able to deploy the model to an iOS device and successfully do inferences. However, after I updated Keras (1.1.0) and Tensorflow (0.11.0) and retrained my model, I recieved the following error when I tried to run the new model on device.

```
Running model failed: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Less' with these attrs
     [[Node: while/Less = Less[T=DT_INT32](while/Merge, while/Less/Enter)]]
```

Heres is how i defined the model

```
inputs = Input(shape=(look_back, feature_count))
encoded = LSTM(50, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
encoded = LSTM(25, return_sequences=True)(encoded)
encoded = LSTM(10)(encoded)

decoded = RepeatVector(look_back)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(feature_count, return_sequences=True)(decoded)

sequence_autoencoder = Model(input=inputs, output=decoded)
sequence_autoencoder.compile(optimizer='RMSprop', loss='mse')
sequence_autoencoder.fit(X_train, X_train,
                          nb_epoch = epochs,
                          batch_size = 32,
                          verbose=1)
```

How can I remove the 'Less' op?

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by an op registration bug in mobile TensorFlow. Details: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4863

Basically, some operators including `Less` and `Add` should be registered for `DT_FLOAT32` and `DT_INT32` in mobile platform but due to the bug they are actually only registered for `DT_FLOAT32`.

I'm not sure when this bug was introduced. Maybe it was introduced after the last working version you used. It's also possible that the old version of Keras was using float `Less` op.

Anyway the root cause was found. Hope it can be solved soon in the next version. Before the elegant fix, you can try some workaround posted in the issue. You have to recompile the TensorFlow library with a few code change like what they did in `Mul` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/26be523ed4ab3a573af7771aec770832d9c30f90):

```
#if defined(__ANDROID_TYPES_SLIM__)
// We only register the first type when we have multi-argument calls in the
// case where we're trying to reduce executable size, but it turns out that the
// int32 version of this op is needed, so explicitly include it.
REGISTER(BinaryOp, CPU, "Mul", functor::mul, int32);
#endif  // __ANDROID_TYPES_SLIM__
```